# Thinking Sphinx - Already have a search method in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, thinking-sphinx

I'd like to use Thinking Sphinx, but I keep having problems because I have a very large rails project and the search method is used in many of my models.  These already existing search methods conflict with Thinking Sphinx's search method.  Is there any way around this?

I'm talking thousands of lines of code I would have to change if I had to change my search method to something else.  I can't seem to  find a way to change the default search method in Thinking Sphinx though either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just answered this on the TS list, but happy to answer here as well :)

There isn't any inbuilt way to do this, but in theory it could be possible. Firstly - Thinking Sphinx adds the class-level search method when you call define_index on a model - so, if you define your own search method after that, it'll overwrite the Thinking Sphinx version.

This means you could just define a new method that does the same thing - here's the code for Model.search:

```
def self.search(*args)
  ThinkingSphinx::Search.new *search_options(args)
end
```

Which you could easily rename to something else:

```
def self.sphinx_search(*args)
  ThinkingSphinx::Search.new *search_options(args)
end
```

The one possible catch with this is that Thinking Sphinx may have expectations internally on the search method existing and behaving as normal. I'm not sure - but give this a spin and see how you go!

**Update**:

As it turns out, the above suggestion doesn't cover all situations and it's still buggy. So, I think the fallback solution is to fork Thinking Sphinx, change the method names, and use your version instead of the canonical one.

Comment: Thanks Pat.  The other person you mentioned was my former boss and I was working with him at the time.  We figured we'd go two different avenues and see what we found.  Didn't expect to be answered by the exact same person on both forums.  :)

Comment: What we found though is that we have a model without a define_index block.  This model has a self.search method that now will not work.  Even with NO define_index block, apparently TS is adding a self.search class method that is overwriting ours. :(